# Why using field `threshold` to hold initial capacity instead of an additional field like `initialCapacity` that is clearer?

Tags: java, hashmap

HashMap's constructor

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty <tt>HashMap</tt> with the specified initial
 * capacity and load factor.
 *
 * @param  initialCapacity the initial capacity
 * @param  loadFactor      the load factor
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is negative
 *         or the load factor is nonpositive
 */
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initial capacity: " +
                initialCapacity);
    if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        initialCapacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
    if (loadFactor <= 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal load factor: " +
                loadFactor);
    this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
    this.threshold = tableSizeFor(initialCapacity); // here, threadshold is actually initial capacity
}
```

I'm a little bit confused when reading the code. My question is that why using field `threshold` to hold initial capacity instead of an additional field like `initialCapacity` that is clearer?

---

Edit: I didn't notice that the constructor accept param `initialCapacity`, I think that the constructor param `initialCapacity` should be `specifiedInitialCapacity`.

Comment: actually, threshold = tableSizeFor(initialCapacity); unless that method is just: private int tableSizeFor(int value) { return value; } there is bound to be a difference

Comment: Are we talking about [this `tableSizeFor`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l377)?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yes.

Comment: `initialCapacity`is passed into the method `tableSizeFor()` which probably does some calculation. To reflect that the parameter `initialCapacity` and the field `threshold` are not the same value a new name is used. If you named the field `initialCapacity` you would confuse a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

Because HashMaps grow more than once, and the threshold is a dynamic value. It changes during the lifecycle of the Map and is adapted, whenever the map is resized.

Javadoc for `threshold` (1.8 openjdk):

```
/**
 * The next size value at which to resize (capacity * load factor).
 *
 * @serial
 */
// (The javadoc description is true upon serialization.
// Additionally, if the table array has not been allocated, this
// field holds the initial array capacity, or zero signifying
// DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.)
int threshold;
```

Since the map can be resized, the initial capacity is just that, and the threshold is only the same initially.